# Ionic Firebase Auth: Cannot read error code

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app with Ionic 3 / Angular 4 / Firebase. The following code authenticates the user properly and the login works.

But I can't read the `error.code`, even if it is in the `console.log(error)`.

Here's my code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .then((result) => {
            // show toast
            this.toast.show("Login was successful");
            // set user to storage
            this.storage.set("user", JSON.stringify(result))
            // restore form submitted state
            this.submitted = false;
            // set nav root to Dashboard
            this.navCtrl.setRoot("DashboardPage");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);

            let errorCode = error.code // THIS CAN'T BE READ
        });
```

The properties of the error object suggested by VS Code are `error.message`, `error.name` and `error.stack`.

Here is the console log:

```
O {code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly 
formatted."}
code: "auth/invalid-email"
message: "The email address is badly formatted."
```

**UPDATE**

Casting to `any` works, but I don't think, that it is the way it was supposed to do.

```
.catch((error: any) => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving `error` the type [`firebase.FirebaseError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.FirebaseError), like this:

```
.catch((error:firebase.FirebaseError) => {
    console.error(error);
    let errorCode = error.code // THIS CAN'T BE READ
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get a new error: `Argument of type '(error: Error) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Error) => any'. Types
            of parameters 'error' and 'a' are incompatible. Type 'Error' is not assignable to type
            'firebase.auth.Error'. Property 'code' is missing in type 'Error'.`

Comment: Yeah I get the same error! But only in the file containing my service, where I have imported firebase.

Comment: Try the type `firebase.FirebaseError` instead.